Android не запоминает мой лаунчер как "Рабочий стол по умолчанию"
Пишу лаунчер для Android:
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:label="System Trusta"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.home.alternate"
                android:value="ANOTHER_APP_PACKAGE" />
        </activity>
    </application>

Само приложение работает и даже есть в списке лаунчеров. Но по умолчанию не закрепляется. То есть при выходе на главный экран кнопкой «домой», каждый раз приходится выбирать средство запуска. Галочку "Запомнить выбор" система игнорирует.

Может проблема в девайсе? Приведите модель.

Тестирую на Mi 9 Lite (MIUI 12), других вариантов не имею, приходится работать с тем, что есть. Ну другие лаунчеры (тк NovaLauncher и тд) работают без проблем. Либо я что-то не дописываю в код, либо нужна интеграция с MIUI - тут не понятно..

Возможно у вас та же проблема: https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/imdbax/mi_10_ultra_miui_12_wont_let_me_set_another/

Неее, я могу выбрать другой лаунчер. И даже свой могу выбрать. Но именно мой не запоминается по умолчанию. Пробовал экспериментировать с манифестом, иногда доходило до того, что не запоминались и другие лаунчеры только изза моего приложения. Видимо оно вызывает конфликт, так как возможно я забыл добавить какую-то библиотеку или что-то там дописать в код
